# ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named <mymodule>", when deploying to Heroku from Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, modulenotfounderror

When deploying my Django app to Heroku, I get a ModuleNotFoundError that states "no module named 'RealisticEstate'". RealisticEstate is the name of my Django project. The program builds no problem, but when I try to deploy I get the following errors:

```
[2021-05-13 21:35:45 -0400] [15610] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
9:35:45 PM web.1 |  [2021-05-13 21:35:45 -0400] [15610] [INFO] Listening at: 
http://0.0.0.0:5000 (15610) 9:35:45 PM web.1 |  [2021-05-13 21:35:45 -0400] [15610] [INFO] Using worker: sync
9:35:45 PM web.1 |  [2021-05-13 21:35:45 -0400] [15613] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15613
9:35:45 PM web.1 |  [2021-05-13 21:35:45 -0400] [15613] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
9:35:45 PM web.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site- packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      worker.init_process()
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      self.load_wsgi()
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      self.callable = self.load()
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/<user>/RealisticEstate/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      mod = importlib.import_module(module)
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
9:35:45 PM web.1 |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
9:35:45 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
9:35:45 PM web.1 |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RealisticEstate'
```

My Procfile is as follows:

```
web: gunicorn RealisticEstate.wsgi
```

My Heroku project is named "realisticestate", but when I tried changing my Procfile to:

```
web: gunicorn realisticestate.wsgi
```

it throws the same error.

Here is the project structure:

```
RealisticEstate
|___config
|   |___static
|   |   |___admin
|   |       |___css     
|   |       |___font
|   |       |___img
|   |       |___js
|   |___ __init__.py
|   |___ asgi.py
|   |___ settings.py
|   |___ urls.py
|   |___ wsgi.py
|
|___mapper
|   |___ migrations
|   |___ utils
|   |   |___ __init.py__
|   |   |___ update_db.py
|   |___ __init.py__
|   |___ admin.py
|   |___ apps.py
|   |___ forms.py
|   |___ models.py
|   |___ tests.py
|   |___ urls.py
|   |___ views.py
|   |___ staticfiles
|
|___ templates
|___ venv
|___ .gitignore
|___ manage.py
|___ models.py
|___ Procfile
|___ requirements.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post your project's directory structure and the whole contents of your `Procfile` please.

Comment: It's been updated above

Comment: Why not `config.wsgi` ? `realisticestate.wsgi` not point to any python file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is true that you need to put project_name in your Procfile, and that because always the folders wraping all the folder have the same name of the folder where **wsgi.py** exists .wich your *Procfile* should point to,but in your case you named it ***config*** so it should be:

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi
```

i personally add it like this:

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

Only what's inside the git root directory (`RealisticEstate`) will be pushed to Heroku, not the directory itself. Your wsgi file is then `config/wsgi.py` therefore you should use:

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi
```